# Add parallel lines inside an irregular polygon QGIS 3.22

Tags: qgis, polygon, distance, parallel-lines

[image][image]I am using QGIS 3.22.10

My end goal is to know the distance a tractor will travel all up when it is seeding an area (the irregular polygon) at 1m distance (single line seeding).

Is there an option to do this with drawn lines also. I am looking to duplicate contour lines throughout these two polygons.

Comment: Isn't it just area of the polygon in square meters?

Comment: Simply answered: yes, it is possible. This is, however, not what you want to know, I guess. So for a more detailed answer, you should start providing more information about what you have, what you tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: I have added an image. I am fairly new to QGIS so apologise. I am looking to duplicate the contour lines within the two polygons with a 1m buffer between, cropping them at the edge of the polygons. I don't need the area of the whole polygon, I will need to know how many meters the total lines in each polygon are and it will also give rough guidance to driver of seeding tractor....I am able to create a vector layer as geom line string as a copy of the contour within the polygon.  I am unable to duplicate this and or crop it to fit polygon.   Hope this helps

Comment: I have also been able to add a1m buffer to this single line

Comment: no height involved only 1m distance apart. (technically they will alter a total of 2m across whole polygon but it is not important for the exercise). The contour is just to follow the pathway, so all the planting lines within the polygon will be same shape as the contour, it is good for reveg of native species.

Comment: What you're asking isn't possible. It's not possible (in general) to mirror contour lines with a 1m buffer, unless the contour lines are all parallel in the first place. The contour lines - as you can see from your image - diverge or converge, and your 1m buffer will need to get narrower or wider than 1m. So you need to re-specify your requirement.

Comment: To me, the question (including image plus your additional comments) is still unclear and does not seem to make sense. Please post an image that shows exactly what you want. You just want to know the accumulated length of the contour lines inside the polygon?

Comment: I've added another image of what I was aiming for. I replicated contour line 1m apart throughout the polygons (as they are 2m contours and only one intersects) then added $length attribute and summed them in excel to find total distance tractor would travel. I probably explained this awfully. There's also probably a much better way to do this than what I ended up doing but I got there in the end

Answer (score 2):

1. [Rasterize](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#gdalrasterize) your line layer with `A fixed value to burn=1`. My start line layer lines are at most about 800 m apart, I set the resolution to 2*2 m in georeferenced units.
2. [Proximity](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasteranalysis.html#gdalproximity) with `A list of pixel values in the source image to be considered target pixels=1` and `The maximum distance to be generated` set to something realistic so you dont create a huge raster. I use 1000 m.
3. Contour lines

[image]